# Errorbars plot too big compared to the bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I can't find the reason why my errorbars are so big compared to my bars?
Thanks a lot!

```
df3
  Amplitudes   QF Detect_Bin        sd
1          3  0.5  0.2118056 0.2909918
2          3    1  0.2037037 0.3012713
3          3 1.25  0.1701389 0.2931458
4          6  0.5  0.5729167 0.4023829
5          6    1  0.4994213 0.4057509
6          6 1.25  0.4085648 0.4043558
7          9  0.5  0.7384259 0.3479116
8          9    1  0.6574074 0.3831921
9          9 1.25  0.5821759 0.4015536
```

```
bar<-ggplot(df3, aes(x= Amplitudes, y= Detect_Bin, fill=Amplitudes))
bar+ 
geom_bar(stat="identity")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Detect_Bin-sd, ymax=Detect_Bin+sd), width = .2, size=0.5)+
facet_wrap(~QF)+
labs(x="Amplitude du SS", y="Moyenne de détection")
```

[Figure plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqbc0.png)

Answer (score 2):

I have replicated your plot and nothing is wrong with the code. You generate the errorbars using `ymin=Detect_Bin-sd` and `ymax=Detect_Bin+sd`. The values of the *sd* column are larger or close to the values in *Detect_bin*. As you can see in the table, the values are correct.

### Data

```
df3 <- data.frame("Amplitudes" = c(3,3,3,6,6,6,9,9,9), "QF" = c(0.5,1,1.25,0.5,1,1.25,0.5,1,1.25), Detect_Bin = c(0.2118056, 0.2037037, 0.1701389, 0.5729167, 0.4994213, 0.4085648, 0.7384259, 0.6574074, 0.5821759), sd = c(0.2909918, 0.3012713, 0.2931458, 0.4023829, 0.4057509, 0.4043558, 0.3479116, 0.3831921, 0.4015536))
df3$Amplitudes <- factor(df3$Amplitudes, levels = c("3","6","9"))


df3 %>% mutate(ymin = Detect_Bin-sd, ymax= Detect_Bin+sd)
```

| Amplitudes | QF | Detect_Bin | sd | ymin | ymax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0.50 | 0.2118056 | 0.2909918 | -0.0791862 | 0.5027974 |
| 3 | 1.00 | 0.2037037 | 0.3012713 | -0.0975676 | 0.5049750 |
| 3 | 1.25 | 0.1701389 | 0.2931458 | -0.1230069 | 0.4632847 |
| 6 | 0.50 | 0.5729167 | 0.4023829 | 0.1705338 | 0.9752996 |
| 6 | 1.00 | 0.4994213 | 0.4057509 | 0.0936704 | 0.9051722 |
| 6 | 1.25 | 0.4085648 | 0.4043558 | 0.0042090 | 0.8129206 |
| 9 | 0.50 | 0.7384259 | 0.3479116 | 0.3905143 | 1.0863375 |
| 9 | 1.00 | 0.6574074 | 0.3831921 | 0.2742153 | 1.0405995 |
| 9 | 1.25 | 0.5821759 | 0.4015536 | 0.1806223 | 0.9837295 |

The negative values in amplitude 3 correspond to the values below zero. From my point of view there is no error in the representation, maybe you do not want that specific plot.

Comment: You are right! My code is ok. In fact i didn't expected was the values taken by sd... Detect_Bin can not be negative, so i was surprised ymin <0 ...